# Adding a Column on onUpgrade in Android followed by a createView might fail

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm adding a column to a table on the onUpgrade as:

> db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + LocationOffLine.TABLE_NAME + " ADD 'Reference' TEXT");

after this im calling a

> db.execSQL();

to create a view with a CREATE VIEW ... AS Select (...)

but it fails since the added column does not exist.
is i just reinstall the app (using the onCreate) the view is created successfully.

Any toughs?

Comment: Do you have data in the database when you upgrade it?

Comment: Yes there is data but since im calling the Add Column i don't see any problem there

Comment: Show the entire CREATE VIEW statement. (Is it also called in `onUpgrade`?)

Answer (score 0):

When you add the new column it doesn't add any data to the new column in old rows. Pulling from that column from an old record will return null. You should be able to add `DEFAULT "your value"` to the end of your alter statement, but some people report that doesn't update old rows either, so you may need to manually iterate through your data and insert a value.